# How to do speech recognition on a single word

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, voice-recognition

I would provide a sound signal of about 2-3 seconds to my neural network. I have trained my network with a single word, like if I speak "Hello" the network may tell if "Hello" is spoken or not, but some other word like "World" is spoken, it will say "Hello" is not spoken. I just want classification of sound if its a specific command or word.
What is the best way to do this, I am not a that much advanced in DNN, I only know about NN and CNN, I want to know if there is some research paper or tutorial, or need some explanation about the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have fixed length speech data you can detect the content using only CNN. You can see that problem as a binary classification (`1` if the spoken word is correct, `0` otherwise).

But first, you need to make the input length is fixed. For example, you use 2 seconds as the fixed length. If the recorded speech is more than 2 seconds, you need to crop it, and if the recorded speech is less than 2 seconds you can pad it with 0 values.

Next, You can either use [raw data (time-domain)](https://ronan.collobert.com/pub/matos/2015_cnnspeech_interspeech.pdf) or [transform your data using some features extractors method (FFT, MFCC, or MFSC)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/CNN_ASLPTrans2-14.pdf). Then, use CNN as you use it to classify the image. You can assume the graphic of the sound wave as a 2D image.

But, If your data have a variety of length, you can combine CNN to detect each phoneme then combine it as a sequence using RNN or HMM. You can read this method also in the mentioned papers.

Comment: Yes, I need to crop, I have thought the sound data in form of a dequeue, I would have a window of 2s, pass this 2 seconds to model, pop from the front of the window a sample, and push the sample recorded at the back and repeat this algorithm

Comment: One more thing I want to ask, say for "hello" word recognition, how much dataset size would provide a considerable good accuracy, if you know this. Otherwise i understood the logic, I would read the papers to implement it. Thanks

Comment: yes, you can use your "window" method. if you use small "shift", It would give some variation of your training data. I can't give an exact number, try with a smaller size (~100 samples for each class) and increase it if the accuracy is still small. To improve accuracy you still need to use some data that have similar sound with "hello".